# Expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns Exception

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I have a table in `MS-Access` database named `ItemRates` which contains columns `ItemID, ItemName, TotalFeet, RatePerItem, TotalRate` and this database is connected with my `java` application.

When i run the following query

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(TotalRate) AS ItemRateSum, TotalFeet FROM ItemRates";
```

I get the following exception

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 expression not in aggregate or
GROUP BY columns: PUBLIC.ITEMRATES.TOTALFEET
```

I have seen other questions related to this exception on `StackOverflow` and one accepted answer suggested to add `GroupBy` clause at the end of the query. I added a `GroupBy` clause

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(TotalRate) AS ItemRateSum, TotalFeet FROM 
ItemRates GROUPBY ItemName";
```

and i got almost same exception (there's a slight difference between two exceptions at the end after the colon)

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 expression not in aggregate or 
GROUP BY columns: GROUPBY.TOTALFEET
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT SUM(TotalRate) AS ItemRateSum, TotalFeet
FROM ItemRates
GROUP BY TotalFeet;
```

That is, `TotalFeet` is not an argument to an aggregation function, so it needs to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That solved the problem. Will accept the answer once time limit is over. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

All columns which are selected and are not part of the aggregate functions have to be included in the group by clause

Comment: SELECT SUM(TotalRate) AS ItemRateSum FROM ItemRates GROUPBY ItemName